# React native fetch request on android work with debugger and don't work without it

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I send a request to the server using the fetch. If the debugger is on, then the answer is 200, and all is well. If I turn off the debugger, request throws me into the catch and shows 500 error. Is it possible to somehow make the query work as debugger?

My request

```
   fetch(path, {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
     },
   })
   .then(response => {
     console.log("TRUE", response)    
     return response;
   })
   .catch( (err) => {
     console.log('Got error:', err);
   });
```

Comment: What is the path? Is it localhost?

Comment: When using `Debug JS Remotely`, the js code actually gets executed by the web browser. What is probably happening is that some part of your request is supported by your browser but not React Native without importing a library

Comment: No, the request goes to Heroku server.
But on iOS it's work with and without debugger

Comment: You don't need to include a library, fetch is included by React Native.